How to use a lot of (somewhat repetitive) known-good examples to improve model performance
I have a single code base, and for each function in each class of that code base, I have generated (e.g.) 100 working variations of that function (tested).
The prompts do not include the original but instead provide context (header file, dependencies) and ask for a generation.
Can this data be used to improve model performance?
Will fine tuning on this data be effective if the prompts for each function are very similar? As in, the same prompt producing 100 (working) variations of a function.
What is the best approach in this case?
Thank you!

Hi douggard,
could you please clarify your question by providing more details on the dataset and the specific task you want to achieve? it is a bit unclear what methodology or approach you're asking about.
